# TERROR MOVIE: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {} VOL VIII

Tags: protractor

I've been checking others threads about this common error and trying to apply what they recommend but still getting same error. I warn you I'm totally newbie at PROTRACTOR.
This it's the first test I'm writting:

```
describe('Just some shitty test', function(){
'use strict';

it('Testing some shitty test', function(){

    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get(browser.baseUrl); 
    });
    /*
        Purpose: 
            1. Getting in "HEALTH CARE PARTNER / ORGANISATION (KND. NR.: 438)" panel
            2. Edit content
            3. Save it
    */

    // First, I find elements I want to test 

    //ANCHOR Bearbeiten
    var $a = $('a','div.m-pane__control');
    //INPUT Name
    var $name = $('input[placeholder="Name"]');
    //SELECT 
    var $select = $('select','m-form__select ng-scope');
    //INPUT Yearly births
    var $yearly = $('input[placeholder="Yearly births"]');
    //INPUT Homepage
    var $homepage = $('input[placeholder="Homepage"]');
    //INPUT Email
    var $email = $('input[placeholder="Email"]');
    //TEXTAREA. two ways to find it
    var $textarea1 = $('textarea[ng-model="model[field.name]"]');
    var $textarea2 = element(by.model('model[field.name]'));
    //BUTTON Speichern
    var $speichern = $('button[ng-click="savebtn()"]');

    // Sequence of actions

    //Is bearbeiten button displayed?
    //expect($a.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    //Click on it!
    //$a.click();

    //Settings
    //$name.sendKeys('John Smith').submit();
    //$yearly.sendKeys('42');
    //$homepage.sendKeys('something');
    //$email.sendKeys('tschues@baba.at');
    //$textarea1.sendKeys('fahren lassen');

    //Save
    //$speichern.click();       });});
```

I don't know if elements I've searched are ok but every time I call `getText()` function or either as `click()`, `sendKeys` or whatever, I always get `Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}`.

What I'm forgetting or doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I saw the movie, it wasn't so scary ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something  like this

```
describe('Just some test', function(){
    var ptor;
    beforeEach(function () {
      browser.get(browser.baseUrl); 
      ptor = protractor.getInstance();
      ptor.waitForAngular();
    });

    it('should do something', function(){
        var aLink = element(by.css('div.m-pane__control'));
        aLink.click();
    });
});
```

Biggest differences are I ask protractor to wait for angular, since it takes some time to get ready and I used the protractor style of finding elements on the page.

Comment: Your welcome. The protractor project is on github. From the testcases that are used in the project you can learn fast how the designer expect you use the framework.